# Can you do a masked URL rewrite to a different protocol (in Apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

Apache 2.2.15; I want to do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site1.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://site2.com [R=301,P,L]
```

But that does not work. I put the P in there thinking it might allow the mod_proxy passthrough/URL masking, so that the site1.com URL remains in the browser despite being forwarded to site2.com.  The real kicker here is that site2 is HTTPS and site1 is not.  I never did a masked rewrite between protocols, any suggestions?

Comment: You need to set up a reverse proxy VirtualHost in Apache. That is, make another VirtualHost with `ProxyPass` directive.

Comment: Keep in mind that using a reverse proxy like this will only use SSL between the server and the final destination, the link from the original client to the server will not be secure.

Comment: Are we saying `ProxyPass / https://site2.com \n ProxyPassReverse / https://site2.com` In a vhost config for site1.com?